# Primitive of ${(a^2-1)x^4+(a^2-2)x^2-1}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to compute the following integral ($x\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<a<1$)
$$
\int\frac{1}{(a^2-1)x^4+(a^2-2)x^2-1}\text{d}x
$$
and Wolfram Alpha in his step-by-step guide is telling me to use partial fractions, but I have no idea how to obtain them. Any help on that or on a more efficient way to attack this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c \ne 0$, then:

$$
a + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4 
= \frac{b^2}{4\,c} - \frac{b^2}{4\,c} + a + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4
= \frac{b^2}{4\,c} - \frac{b^2 - 4\,a\,c}{4\,c} + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4
$$

and if $b^2 - 4\,a\,c > 0$ it's possible to define $d \equiv \sqrt{b^2 - 4\,a\,c}$, from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4 
& = \frac{b^2}{4\,c} - \frac{d^2}{4\,c} + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4 \\
& = \frac{b^2 + 4\,b\,c\,x^2 + 4\,c^2\,x^4 - d^2}{4\,c} \\
& = \frac{\left(b + 2\,c\,x^2\right)^2 - d^2}{4\,c} \\
& = \frac{\left(b + 2\,c\,x^2 - d\right)\left(b + 2\,c\,x^2 + d\right)}{4\,c} \\
& = c\left(\frac{b - d}{2\,c} + x^2\right)\left(\frac{b + d}{2\,c} + x^2\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

In light of all this, it follows that:

$$
\small
\int \frac{1}{a + b\,x^2 + c\,x^4}\,\text{d}x 
= \int \frac{1}{c\left(\frac{b - d}{2\,c} + x^2\right)\left(\frac{b + d}{2\,c} + x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x
= \frac{1}{d}\left(\int \frac{1}{\frac{b-d}{2\,c}+x^2}\,\text{d}x
- \int \frac{1}{\frac{b+d}{2\,c}+x^2}\,\text{d}x\right).
$$

Comment: Where does this formula come from?

Comment: I hadn't seen the update, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solve the equation
$$(a^2-1)x^4+(a^2-1)x^2-1=0$$ and convert you denominator in a product form.
The result should be this here $$-{\frac {1}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) {a}^{2}}}+{\frac {{a}^{2}-1}{
 \left( {a}^{2}{x}^{2}-{x}^{2}-1 \right) {a}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Taking $x^2=A$ here may make the factorization easier